# Python, can't download file from url, get a kind of home page for each files

Tags: python, url, download, request

I want to download several files of different types from an url by iterating through the names.
How it looks like :

[image]

I'm trying with request lib and the following code :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from getpass import getpass


name = 'test.xls'
url_strat = '***'
output = open('data/test/' + name ,'wb')

resp = requests.get(url_strat + name,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', getpass()))
resp.encoding = 'utf-8'


output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
print(url_strat + name)
```

But I don't get the file I want, for each file I tried I get the same result, a kind of home page.

To access the data I need to enter my username and a password once

Do someone know what is wrong or what could be wrong here ?
I can download the files by clicking on the link, but I want to do it automatically because there are a lot of files.

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: at the end of the code, I print the complete url, and when I click on it, the file is succesfully downloaded. But with resp = requests.get(url_strat + name,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', getpass()))
I get the weird same result, home page like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from getpass import getpass
resp = requests.get(url_strat + name, auth=('username', getpass()))
```

Requests does http basic authentication. You don't have to specify it explicitly. Your issue may be due to certificate error. If so try `resp = requests.get(url_strat + name, verify=False, auth=('username', getpass()))` but this is insecure and you shouldnt do this.

Comment: Thx for the answer ! Unfortunately it's was the issue ...

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer, if you found it useful.